# Obtaining coefficients when doing Taylor

Tags: limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I've been looking at the solution to this question for some time and I can't workout why the coefficients of $x^4$, $x^6$ and $x^8$ are $0$. I'm also wondering where the $x^4/2$ came from in the 2nd line. I know that in the solution the Taylor polynomials of the terms are used but that's about all I know.

Here is the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTrLT.png):
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\cos(x)\sin(x^2)}{\ln(1+2x^4)}&=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-(1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\mathcal O (x^4))(x^2+\mathcal O (x^6))}{2x^4+\mathcal O(x^8)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x^4}{2}+\mathcal O(x^6)}{2x^4+\mathcal O(x^8)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\mathcal O (x^2)}{2+\mathcal O (x^4)}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}

Thanks

Comment: The coefficients are not 0. That's the Big-O notation. In short, it means that the higher order terms $x^4,x^6,x^8\dots$ can be neglected as $x\to{0}$.

Comment: The $x^4/2$ came from the expansion of the terms in brackets: $(1-x^2/2+O(x^4))(x^2+O(x^6))$, specifically the term obtained by multiplying the $x^2/2$ in the first bracket and $x^2$ in the second bracket

Comment: Thanks for your comments! So does the (x^4/2)/2x^4 go to 1/4 because of the Big-O (because I would've expected it to be 0).

Comment: From the second line to the third line, we divide by $x^4$ throughout. This is allowed in Big-O notation, so the terms in the O are reduced also. From the third line to last line, we take the limit, and the terms in O go to 0, and we are left with $\frac{0.5}{2}$. Read up more on the Big O notation and its properties if you are still unclear. :)